# For testing windows applications - Is there any tool developed in Java?

Tags: testing, automation

I am familiar with jwinauto for windows applications however I am looking for a better tool to automate the test of Windows Applications developed in Java or JRuby or Jython.

I have seen white for automating tests on web application and windows application by accessing the controls and automating them. However I want to find a white equivalent for windows applications (written in Java) preferably that is open source.

Answer (score 0):

[FEST](http://fest.easytesting.org/) is a nice tool to test Java UIs.

Comment: Thanks Thomas... but im looking out for tools which can test GUI Applications apart from Java based GUI Apps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [robot framework](http://www.robotframework.org). It is written in python and can be run with jython.

Robot framework is a keyword driven testing framework. Keywords can be written in python, but if you're running with jython you can also create keywords out of POJOs (plain ol' java objects).